# I have a serious issue with the trigger of the CRM that am developing with GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

I have a serious big problem with the trigger of the CRM that am developing for a client to with Google apps script and all Google apps (calendar,sheet,forms...)

Some time the trigger does not execute On-form submit and i have a lot of functionality like (Get Update URL,Get prefilled URL from Google forms,Export to calendar,Merge...)

Even i tried with TriggerBuilder of Google developpers https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/document-trigger-builder Any ideas!!??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be ongoing issues with Form Submit Triggers recently (Feb 2015) which are resulting in both "lost" and "duplicate" trigger events.

Presently there is no direct solution that I am aware of, I don't believe the problem is related to the content of the scripts but rather an underlying problem with Google not being able to dispatch the trigger events reliably.

Yesterday the "lost" triggers issue was especially noticeable, while the duplicates issue seems to have been reduced or eliminated.

Unfortunately I don't have a good solution to handle this problem automatically. In some cases I have provided my clients with a spreadsheet menu option in the Form Responses spreadsheet which allows the user to "re-process" a selected row.

You can also use Notifications in the destination spreadsheets to alert you anytime the sheet is modified, this combined with emails send from your OnFormSubmit triggers can at least provide a way to monitor the issue and potentially open the door to solutions.

In the case of a CRM solution, it might make sense to have a "cleanup" or "maintenance" script which runs on a fixed schedule, cross checks your various spreadsheets and makes sure that everything has been handled as it should. This would be useful as a sort of catch-all solution that could fix other kinds of errors as well as this form trigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems with onOpen in the SpreadsheetApp. I managed to get it working by going to the Resources menu in the script editor and adding the trigger there, though I shouldn't have had to do this, and it's completely redundant. I occasionally get an error in my email hours later informing me that a trigger failed to execute, usually because of authorization problems. Without having any other details about your problem, I suggest you manually execute the trigger function from within the script editor and inspect the event object using either Logger or even `ui.alert()` if you have to. That may seem obvious, but you haven't specified your situation in very much detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replay ,but i have  many section such as management Client ,Management Invoice,management training....             I need trigger to get all procces automated  but the script is not stable and when i execute the trigger manually it work the way i want.
here are Issues : 
1 ) form submit triggers disappearing and not firing thereafter,
2) form submit triggers not firing for some percentage of submits.

Comment: Can you describe your situation in more detail? Where are the triggers? In the code or set up in the script menu?